# Display real time discount price everywhere

Tags: magento

I have a store with different customer group.in which all customer has a specific discount for all product.Suppose customer group A has 10 customer and discount is also 10% on all product. Discount is decided from one of my API site so it's a real time discount for different customer group When customer logging in that belongs to customer group A he/she is able to see price with 10% discount every where (Product listing,product view,and with whole check out process.)

i can achieve this by calling below code but it display only on cart page not every where.

```
checkout_cart_product_add_after
```

observer function

```
$item = $observer->getQuoteItem();
 $product = $observer->getProduct();
 $price = $product->getPrice();
 //print_r($item->toArray());exit;
 // Discounted 25% off
 $percentDiscount = 0.25;

 // This makes sure the discount isn't applied over and over when refreshing
 $specialPrice = $product->getPrice() - ($product->getPrice() * $percentDiscount);
 // Make sure we don't have a negative
 if($specialPrice>0){
    $item->setCustomPrice($specialPrice);
    $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($specialPrice);
    $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
    }
```

How can i achieve this Please help

Comment: I dont think this can be done through observers, instead you need to manually code eveywhere you want to show discounted price. for ex: product list, sidebar widgets, mini cart etc

Answer (score 1):

Same way by using event observer you can achieve discount for product price for product listing page:

```
<catalog_product_collection_load_after>
    <observers>
        <Your_Module_Observer>
            <type>model</type>
            <class>your_module/Observer/class>
            <method>modifyPrices</method>
        </Your_Module_Observer>
    </observers>
</catalog_product_collection_load_after>

$products = $observer->getCollection();
foreach( $products as $product )
{
    $product->setPrice( $myCustomPrice );
}
```